# Installing SharePoint Designer 32-bit versus 64-bit

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, administration, configuration, installation

I want to install SharePoint Designer inside my PC, to be able to access our SharePoint site collections. Now my PC has the following specifications:

- Windows 7 Professional. 64-bit
- MS office 32-bit.

Now I download the 64-bit of SharePoint Designer, but when I tried installing it I got the following error:

[image]

so I am not sure if downloading the SharePoint Designer 32-bit will be a problem ? or it is better to have 64-bit ???

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sharepoint designer consider as a part of the office family so that its version should match with other installed office products.

In your case you have 64 bit of Windows and 32 bit of office so you need 32 bit of designer.

Now either reinstall the office with 64 bit or install the sharepoint designer with 32 bit

https://ofaolain.com/blog/2015/02/05/get-past-sharepoint-designer-installation-error/

Comment: but is having SPD 64-bit provides extra features or capabilities that 32-bit does not provide ?

Comment: That's correct then you have to reinstall office with 64bit. You can't have mix office products

Comment: so you mean it is better to get the 64-bit of sharepoint designer ?

Comment: Yes it is better. Also read this article to understand difference and advantages https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office2010/2010/02/23/understanding-64-bit-office/

Comment: i already read this link, it mainly talk that using 64-bit provides better future flexibility and performance,,, but it is not easy to un-install the whole office right now... so not sure if i can have SPD 32-bit working in my case?and will uing SPD 32-bit can affect the sharepoint site collection in a way or another?

Comment: It's not feature issue both version offering same set of features but only issue is performance. 64 bit give better performance as compare to 32 bit. If you go through the blog then you will understand the benifits. But if you don't want uninstall the office then 32 bit SPD is ok.

Comment: so for now i can use the SPD 32-bit,,, and in the future if i consider using office 64-bit i can install the SPD 64-bit .. i was afraid that for a reason or another using SPD 32-bit to access my sharepoint sites, can change the sharepoint site collections features , version , downsize its capabilties or any thing else.... not sure if my worries are valid !!

Comment: Your worries are not valid. As I said both versions are same just performance difference.

Comment: one more question to make sure i do understand the situation correctly ... Now let say i access a site collection using sharepoint designer 2013 32-bit and i create a new list workflow... will the generated workflow be exactly the same as the list workflow i can create using sharepoint designer 64-bit??.. or the workflow created from SPD 32-bit will be a 32-bit workflow ,, while the workflow created using SPD 64-bit will be a 64-bit workflow ???

Comment: They will be same

Answer (score 1):

it will not, download the other version

Comment: but is using SPD 32-bit provides less features and capabilities compared to 64-bit ?

Comment: can you advice what you refer to when you said "it will not"??

Comment: whn you get that pop up message, the only thing to do is to download the other version. There is no way to bypass that message. The 2 versions are exactly alike in terms of features. Just dowload the other and the installation will progress smoothly

Comment: Now let say i create a list workflow using SPD 32-bit , and other workflow using SPD 64-bit .. will the first workflow be a 32-bit workflow , while the other will be 64-bit workflow ?  or the two workflows will be the same it term of everything ?

Comment: Workflows are not standalone pieces of software so they will be the same

Comment: so let me ask a more general question ,, will any thing created using SPD 32-bit be exactly the same as the ones created using SPD 64-bit ??

Comment: yes, however the 64 bit/32bit difference is a difference in how the processor handles the memory, therefore related to sharepoint as a bicycle is related to a fish. No relation at all.